# Which is the simplest way to add  a captcha to a Django site?

Tags: python, django, captcha

I want to add a Captcha on my Django site. I found one way to do this, which is using [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha), but I want to know... Is it easy enough?

And which is the simplest way to add a captcha?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, reCaptcha is easy and works well.

I use it on many sites.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [django-simple-captcha](http://code.google.com/p/django-simple-captcha/) on a few sites. It works pretty well, is easy to setup and customizable.